# Setting the OpenGL version to 2.0 appears to do nothing, as 3.3+ features still work

Tags: opengl

Someone was asking me for a test with OpenGL 2.x since they have hardware that supports only up to OpenGL 2.1.

I figured I'd try it out by setting the window hints in GLFW to use the major/minor version of 2 and 0.

Problem is I'm still using `#version 330` in my shaders, and it works. However, it would not let me use the hints of GL version 2 when I was leaving on a Core profile (by accident). This seems to indicate that my version choice is doing something, but not what I expect.

I want to restrict myself to 2.1 to see if my application would run, and if it doesn't, then see what I can change to make it work. Problem is I don't have any 2.1 hardware since my computers are all 2015 or later.

Is there a way I can emulate 2.1 (on Windows) somehow and have it crash/die if I try using features it doesn't support? Apparently the hints I'm using are not helping.

Comment: Get cheeky with Mesa's [`MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE`](https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html) envvar :)

Comment: Some virtual machine software can only work with OGL <=2.1. You can install Windows XP in a VM and do tests there.

Comment: @Ripi2 Do you have any more info?

Comment: As sidi77 answered, when you ask for a OGL 2.1 some drives give you that versioin, while others give a higher one. Something you can try is setting `1.20` as `#version` in your shaders, and 2.1 for GLFW context-command, and see what it returned. OTOH, a VM that used to be only OGL 2.1 capable is VirtualBox

Comment: @Ripi2 Thanks very much, that was the info I was looking for, going to investigate

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the major/minor version flags don't set the version of your OpenGL context but the required feature set. So if you set the flags to 3.3 for example you will usually get a 4.5 or 4.6 context as those version are typically the latest OpenGL versions your GPU supports that is compatible with OpenGL 3.3. Getting a OpenGL 2.1 Core context should be impossible as the defining feature of the core context is that it doesn't support some OpenGL 1.0-2.1 functionality. So this isn't really surprising.

I think your best option here is to use headers that only contain OpenGL 2.1 functions. [GLAD](https://glad.dav1d.de/) for examples allows you to specify which version you want to generate headers for.